# Quickly Toggle MvcBuildViews in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Does anyone know a way to quickly toggle the MVC project attribute 'MvcBuildViews' without having to do the Unload Project -> Edit -> Change -> Reload Project process?

Comment: This is one of the reasons I use WebSite instead of WebApplication, specially for large sites with lots of pages and views.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  You could create a New solution configuration, called QuickDebug say, and have a different configuration within your proj file for this which would not build your views.